# Ordered statistics, joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $X_1, X_2 \ldots $ be i.i.d. r.v.s with CDF $F$, and let $M_n = \max(X_1, X_2,...,X_n)$. Find
the joint distribution of $M_n$ and $M_{n+1}$, for each $n\ge1$.

My solution is the following:

The probability $P(M_n \le t, M_{n+1} \le k)$ has two cases. Either $k \lt t$ or $k \ge t$.

In case $k \lt t$:
$$P(M_n \le t, M_{n+1} \le k) = P(M_n \le t| M_{m+1} \le k)P(M_{n+1} \le k) = $$
$$P(X_1 \le t, X_2 \le t, \ldots X \le t|X_1 \le k, \ldots X_{n+1} \le k)F(k)^{n+1} = F(k)^{n+1}$$

In case $k \ge t$:
$$P(M_n \le t, M_{n+1} \le k) = P(M_n \le t| M_{m+1} \le k)P(M_{n+1} \le k) = $$
$$P(X_1 \le t, X_2 \le t, \ldots X \le t|X_1 \le k, \ldots X_{n+1} \le k)F(k)^{n+1} = $$
$$P(X_1 \le t | X_1 \le k) \ldots P(X_n \le t | X_n \le k)F(k)^{n+1} = F(t)^nF(k)$$

This means:
$$P(M_n \le t, M_{n+1} \le k) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      F(k)^{n+1} & k \lt t \\
      F(t)^nF(k) & k \ge t\
      \
\end{array} 
\right. $$

I'd appreciate if somebody could check if my reasoning is correct.